# Plotting an inequality in 3D

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I would like to plot the following `(s,k,w)` domain:

```
s<0 & k>3+11.1282s^2 & 
(1/32)(27-3*sqrt(6)+sqrt(111+46*sqrt(6))[(k-3)^2/s]+10s > w >[(k-3)^2/s] + 10s
```

where s ranges from -10 to 0, k from 3 to 20 and w from -50 to 0.

I ran the following code:

```
s = linspace(-10,0);
k = linspace(3,20);
w = linspace(-50,0);
[S,K,W] = meshgrid(s,k,w);
I = (K>3+11.1282*S.^2) & (W > ((K-3).^2)./S + 10*S) & ( W < (((K-3).^2)./(32*S))*(27-sqrt(111+46*sqrt(6))-3*sqrt(6))+10*S);
figure(1)
scatter3(S(I),K(I),W(I),'filled')
xlabel('skewness')
ylabel('kurtosis')
zlabel('hyper skewness')

az = 0;
el = 90;
view(az, el);
```

where `view(az,el)` gives a perspective of skewness vs kurtosis (s vs k). However, this looks really strange. Is it due `scatter3`? Any alternative suggestions to plot the existence domain?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "strange"? What's the expected result?

Comment: Since we have the condition k>3+11.1281s^2 I would expect the plot (s vs k) would show a parabola. Looking at the plot, I can see the parabola shape, however it would be nice if the entire region was filled up.

Comment: EDIT: increasing the number of space points gives better visual results. 
Setting for instance s = linspace(-10,0,200), I can observe the shape of the parabola. However, it would be better if the whole space was filled in.

Comment: That is indeed scatter's fault. `scatter()` shows your data points as little circles and unless you draw loads of circles, it won't give the "fill surface" effect. I'd suggest you to check `fill3()`

Comment: I tried to run: fill3(S(I),K(I),W(I),1). The resulting plot is not what I expected until I realized that the fill command interpolates polygons. Unfortunately, the result looks quite messy. Any idea on how to fix this?